# How to apply DataTemplate Style using DataTrigger

Tags: wpf, coding-style, datatrigger, contentcontrol

I'm trying to apply a ContentTemplate based on a Binding value. Problem is, it's not working.

I have a Default template, called TemplateA, I then want to display a style based on a databound value - being either TemplateA or TemplateB.

If I comment out the Default template, neither template is selected.

I have checked my databound value, the value is ok.

Can you see where I'm going wrong?

Here is the ListDataView

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="ListDataView" />
```

It's located within the Resources section of the Window, ListDataView is attached to an ObservableCollection within code.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TemplateA">
    <TextBlock Text="Template A" />
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="TemplateB">
    <TextBlock Text="Template B" />
</DataTemplate>

    <ContentControl x:Name="LISTINGCONTROLA">
    <ContentControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource TemplateA}" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={StaticResource ListDataView}, Path=ListType}" Value="TEMPLATEA">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource TemplateA}" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Source={StaticResource ListDataView}, Path=ListType}" Value="TEMPLATEB">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource TemplateB}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ContentControl.Style>
</ContentControl>
```

Comment: Can you include the definition of your templates as well?

Comment: The templates look fine - can you post the definition of `ListDataView`?

Comment: I've added the XAML definition of the ListDataView, the source of the ListDataView is set in code. The source is an ObservableCollection.

Comment: Can you post the code that sets `ListDataView`?

Answer (score 1):

Using a WPF **DataTemplateSelector** might be of help
http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-how-to-use-a-datatemplateselector

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely because your binding is pointing to a property on the `CollectionViewSource` itself, and that class does not have a property named `ListType` so there is no value to bind to (hence the default always being used).

Where is the `ListType` property that you are trying to bind to?

Comment: As a test, I inserted a Label in my UI to show the value: <Label Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource ListDataView}, Path=ListType}" FontSize="20" FontFamily="Arial" Foreground="White"/>, the content of the Label shows the correct value is being derrived through ListDataView.ListType.

Comment: Can you try adding this: `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource ListDataView}}" />` somewhere and let me know what text is displayed in the new TextBlock?

Comment: I added the TextBlock - it was blank. As a test, I added ,Path=ListType and it displayed the value I need to select TemplateB.

Comment: I'm actually just trying to work out what type `ListDataView` is, as `CollectionViewSource` does not have a property named `ListType`.  Can you put a breakpoint in somewhere and check what type it is?